# Modeling Class hierarchy that may change during runtime

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, class-design, subclassing

I've been building an application that processes documents through different filters.

I have a class (or better as an interface for creating test-doubles?) called `Document`. The `Document` class contains many fields and therefore I was thinking about using the Builder pattern for construction.

Now, there are certain "specialized" documents that contain additional fields (let's call it `SpecialDocument`). The obvious solution would be to extend the `Document` class. However, how would I then (during runtime) take a `Document` instance and make it a `SpecialDocument` instance? Remember that the construction of the `Document` instance is quite complex, therefore I think, a copy-constructor is too tedious and error-prone (when adding a filed etc.).

Another solution that I can think of is to pass the original `Document` instance to the `SpecialDocument` constructor and then delegate all document calls to that instance.

Or should I maybe just add those fields from `SpecialDocument`to the `Document` class and then provide optional getters, like so `Optional<String> getSpecialField`? This last option seems to be the least preferable since it mixes concepts and the client would never be sure about the type of document it is dealing with (besides having to deal with the optional first).

Is there a simpler and more elegant way to model this scenario?

Thank you very much for you advice.

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance <- this approach.

Comment: As @ThomasJunk points out in his comment, Inheritance is not very flexible. Also, I find it's more helpful to focus on real-world, concrete examples. When you try to design something that's too generalized, it leads to [speculative generality](https://refactoring.guru/smells/speculative-generality), which is a design smell.

Answer (score 6):

The class of an object is not supposed to change during the object life-cycle.  If you think it should, there must be something wrong in the design.

The kind of challenge that you describe is usually addressed with:

- the [decorator pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html):  a decorator `SpecialDocument` would add some responsibilities to the base class `Document`, such as some more methods, or some more properties, or both together.
- the [entity component system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system):  an entity `Document` would have some components such as `SpecialDocument`, which would define a set of properties and behaviors.
- a higher level of abstraction:  `Document` would be defined in such a way that a [strategy](https://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html) could e set dynalically to alter its behavior.

The common denominator behind these design patterns is the creative use of composition that is [preferred over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) whenever the thought of changin class dynamically crosses your mind.

Answer (score 1):

Most often I'd do this:

```
class SpecialDocument {
    Document getDocument();
    String getField1();
    String getField2();
}
```

The `SpecialDocument` doesn't extend `Document`, instead it contains a reference to a Document which is returned upon request.

1. This avoids creating a complex copy constructor
2. This avoids creating a bunch of delegation methods
3. This allows a function to explicitly take either a `Document` or `SpecialDocument` depending on what the function needs.